# Can not find setRotation/setOrientation value for Vertical

Tags: android, rotation, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a `RelativeLayout` in Java.

The problem is that I can not find a value that makes my code fit with a vertical layout:

```
//Build version is just to avoid the deprecated setOrientation
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    relative.setRotation(HORIZONTAL);
}
else {
    relative.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
}
```

It works for `HORIZONTAL`, but not for `VERTICAL`. I have tried `PORTRAIT` and `VERTICAL` and Eclipse does not give me any response (no correcting or quick fixes) to solve this problem.

Does anyone know what would work for a horizontal rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RelativeLayout` layout does not have orientation. That is, all the components in the layout are relative to other components.

The `LinearLayout` is the guy who can be set HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL

Comment: Seems logical, but I could call relative.setRotation(HORIZONTAL); for RelativeLayout.

Comment: But what is the value for the LinearLayout? Vertical does not work.

Comment: **rotation!=orientation.** What do you need? To rotate the view in degrees, or change its orientation between Horizontal and Vertical? You could call it because: `setRotation() - Sets the degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point.`, but I believe this is not what you need.

Comment: Like when you set a LinearLayout to Vertical in xml and all Views are stacked underneath each other.

Comment: No, you can't do that in `RelativeLayout`.